# Add instance elements to an instantiated parent

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working with four prefabs, "Elements_" is the parent, content_image, content_tittle and content_Options are the children. Inside a for I am adding a number at the end of your name to put them inside the father. Any idea how to do it?

[image: object hierarchy]

Comment: Hi there. Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Content_image_1, Content_tittle_1 and Content_Options_1 to be children of elements_1, you can do so:

```
 public GameObject[] Elements;


    public GameObject aux;
    public int numberofchildren=3;

    //...

    //instances yours objects

    //...


    public void makeChildren()
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < numberofchildren; i++)
        {

            aux = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Content_image_" + i);
            aux.transform.parent = Elements[i].transform;

            aux = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Content_tittle_" + i);
            aux.transform.parent = Elements[i].transform;

            aux = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Content_Options_" + i);
            aux.transform.parent = Elements[i].transform;

        }
    }
}
```

If you want to undo this action you can do this:

```
public void undoChildren(){
for(int i=0;i<numberofchildren;i++){
Elements[i].transform.DetachChildren();
}
}
```

Remember to add the tags to each prefab

I hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you for answering, you see, my problem is that I must automate it with a cycle, that "Element_" + n is a rectransform and if for example I have Element_1, then the content that ends in 1 get into it. Everything automated. I'm using prefabs. Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: ok, I made another option, comment if that's what you were looking for